# Why send account creation instruction with method? + how to do it in frontend with multiple signers?

Tags: anchor, account, phantom, transaction

Hi I'm studying this often cited custom token [escrow program](https://github.com/ironaddicteddog/anchor-escrow/blob/master/programs/anchor-escrow/src/lib.rs) on Anchor in order to create something like it with a frontend.  My question is about the creation of the EscrowAccount. (Account that holds the information of the escrow/exchange of coins.)

```
    #[account(zero)]
pub escrow_account: Box<Account<'info, EscrowAccount>>,
...
#[account]
pub struct EscrowAccount {
    pub initializer_key: Pubkey,
    pub initializer_deposit_token_account: Pubkey,
    pub initializer_receive_token_account: Pubkey,
    pub initializer_amount: u64,
    pub taker_amount: u64,
}
```

I was wondering why they send a createInstruction in the [typescript testfile](https://github.com/ironaddicteddog/anchor-escrow/blob/master/tests/anchor-escrow.ts) instead of just initializing the account with init?  What is the benefit?

```
 await program.rpc.initialize(
  vault_account_bump,
  new anchor.BN(initializerAmount),
  new anchor.BN(takerAmount),
  {
    accounts: {
      initializer: initializerMainAccount.publicKey,
      vaultAccount: vault_account_pda,
      mint: mintA.publicKey,
      initializerDepositTokenAccount: initializerTokenAccountA,
      initializerReceiveTokenAccount: initializerTokenAccountB,
      escrowAccount: escrowAccount.publicKey,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    },
    instructions: [
      await program.account.escrowAccount.createInstruction(escrowAccount),
    ],
    signers: [escrowAccount, initializerMainAccount],
  }
);
```

And if this is the way to go, how do you replicate sending an instruction within the program instruction with multiple signers from a client through phantom wallet?  Can you just pass EscrowAccount as a signer after generating the address on the client?  It seems to error when I try that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely [here](https://github.com/ironaddicteddog/anchor-escrow/blob/master/programs/anchor-escrow/src/lib.rs#L19-L50), you would notice that data is written to the `escrow_account`. A Solana smart contract(program) can only write data to an Account If the Solana program owns the Account. The `createInstruction` basically does an Instruction to create an Account that is owned by the current Solana program. Once this Account is owned by the current executing program, the `initialize` instruction can then write data to the Account.